# Memory management in python loops

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a requirement where I need to loop in ladder fashion. It looks something like this.

```
for i in [i1,i2,.....]:
    for j in [j1,j2,.....]:
        for k in [k1,k2,.....]:
            for l in [l1,l2,.....]:
                for m in [m1,m2,.....]:
                        loop_variables = some computation on i,j,k,l,m
                        np.save('matrix.npy',loop_variables)
```

This code made my laptop freeze. So, I used `itertools`, `del`, `gc` in the following manner.

```
import itertools
import gc
i = [i1,i2,.....]
j = [j1,j2,.....]
k = [k1,k2,.....]
l = [l1,l2,.....]
m = [m1,m2,.....]
lst = [i,j,k,l,m]
f_lst = itertools.product(*lst)
del i,j,k,l,m, lst
for i,j,k,l,m in f_lst:
    loop_variables = some computation on i,j,k,l,m
    np.save('matrix.npy',loop_variables)
    del loop_variables, i,j,k,l,m
    gc.collect()
```

But the problem persists. I have following questions

1. Is above code any better in solving ladder-looping
2. how should I change the above code so that it does not freeze after certain time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cost to opening the file each time.

In general there is a trade off between how much CPU you use in the inner loop vs. how much RAM you consume to reduce the CPU use. i.e. do you collect the result and write out later (and possibly run out of memory while collecting).

The following is a jupyter notebook result for a trimmed version of your example. A big speed up for using 'with'.

```py
import numpy as np
import os

%%timeit
try:
    os.remove('a.npy')
except:
    pass
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        x = np.arange(10)
        np.save('a.npy', x)
# 36 ms ± 746 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
try:
    os.remove('b.npy')
except:
    pass
with open('b.npy', 'wb') as f:
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            x = np.arange(10)
            np.save(f, x)
# 11.9 ms ± 184 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Edit: numpy doc's indicate save appends however 'a.npy' and 'b.npy' are not the same size so ... I'd not trust 'a.npy'.